# How can I make my Google Photos accessible & searchable for the Creative Commons?

Tags: google-photos

I want to add my photos to shared albums on Google Photos and have these accessible under a Creative Commons license. That is, other people should be able to find them when they perform a Google Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the Google Photos platform. There used to be a way to do it through Google+/Picasa, but this was removed around 2014.

You can try [500px](https://500px.com/) or [Flickr](https://flickr.com/) instead. Both sites offer you licensing options and images will be included in Google Image Search and work with its license filter.